# Receiving authentication error from AWS SES despite TLS1.2

Tags: .net-core, smtp, amazon-ses

Why might attempts to send emails using code return an authentication error from AWS SES?

I thought it might be due to recent changes to the minimum TLS version. But Wireshark says that the initial "Client Hello" is using TLS1.2.

It immediately returns a fatal error that has the description "Protocol Version".

There's some other code on the server that uses a different runtime that sends emails ok and it uses the same credentials to connect.

The environment that doesn't work is .net core.